# when did Windows.InvalidateRect got overloaded

Tags: delphi

function InvalidateRect(hWnd: HWND; **const lpRect: TRect;** bErase: BOOL): BOOL;

function InvalidateRect(hWnd: HWND; **lpRect: PRect;** bErase: BOOL): BOOL;

In XE2's Windows unit there are two overloaded definitions. In some cases this requires special treatment than earlier Delphi versions, where only latter declaration was present.

The question is: which Delphi version 1st introduced this overloading ?

Comment: In which case this *requires special treatment* ? Just always use the second overload and you'll be fine.

Comment: D2007 only has the second version, so it was after that anyway. Not sure why it would matter, though; as @TLama says, if you just use that one you have no issues.

Comment: So it was introduced in Delphi 2009... There is the mentioned overload.

Comment: @TLama - make an answer please

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [`InvalidateRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145002%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function overload:

```
function InvalidateRect(hWnd: HWND; const lpRect: TRect; bErase: BOOL): BOOL;
```

has been introduced in Delphi 2009. Although, you don't need to make any conditional function calls of it, when you'll call the function (overload) with the following (correct) prototype:

```
function InvalidateRect(hWnd: HWND; lpRect: PRect; bErase: BOOL): BOOL;
```

That one should exist in all versions of Delphi (at least those, with minimum of Windows 2k support).

Comment: Good find. ;) I do agree: If you're writing code for D2009+, you can use the 'new' declaration, which is more Delphi-like, hiding the pointers, but as soon as your code needs to work in older versions too, I think you'd better use that one everywhere than using a define to switch between them.

Comment: the problem is with another library that declared both variants, probably aiming at aiding making older Delphi source-compatible with newer Delphi. However in newer Delphi this results that when two units (Windows and this lib) are `used` that both declares the same `overloaded` function - `ambiguous call` occurs unless function is fully qualified with unit name. The latter somewhat however defeats the idea of source-level compatibility

Comment: @GolezTrol for me the new declaration is better not just because it is Pascal-like - but because it is type-safe. OTOH i'd better just see Delphi having enforced default `$T+` setting instead of keeping Pascal's stupid "Pointer's are untyped" legacy. Damn! `array of X` and `TArray<X>` are different types, but `^string` and `^integer` are the same ("are assignment-compatible" in docwiki jargon) !